# "Quite a combo" - meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I found this phrase in a comment on a song - "I really like this song, and I really like how diverse Shawn's family is, that's quite a combo."

It seems, that it's a some kind of idiom.

I really can't make sense of this expression. Could someone explain?
Google and translators didn't help ))

Comment: Combo is a short form of "combination". It seems that the combination of the song and the diversity of the family appeal to the person who said what you quote. Alternatively (hard to tell without more context), a combo can also refer to a small musical ensemble, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_ensemble.

Comment: Did the comment really spell it as *shawns?* Because I am thinking *Shawn's* is the proper form, if we are talking about a first name.

Comment: painful - "combo" can mean a musical group; but "quite a combo" is a completely commonplace, well-established idiom.

Comment: Please try to make corrections to obvious spelling mistakes before posting. I will edit the question. Please provide the name of the band or musical group.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it's a common idiom.

It simply draws attention to a pair, or group, of things which are "surprising together".

It simply means: "that's a surprising combination!" - that's it.

So, I tell you I have a Ferrari and a Volvo. You say "that's quite a combo!" Again, you're simply pointing out "that's a surprising combination!"

(Just FTR in the example it's not clear if the writer is talking about "Shwan's family" ("they're quite a combo!") or "the family plus the song" ("that song and that family are quite a combo!").)

Note that it can be used in a **negative** sense, or, just as a positive exclamation.

For example, say you offered me to eat "sushi with curry".  I might say "oh dear - that's quite a combo!"  Note that in this example, it is a **polite** way of saying "that's stupid and horrible."

On the other hand, you offer me chocolate and martinis, I say "That's quite a combo!" with no negative meaning, I'm just saying "that's a surprising combination!" - I may go on to say "That's quite a combo, I love it, let's eat."

That's all there is to it.

Comment: If you google the OP's phrase you will see it is used here: http://www.last.fm/music/Shawn+Lee's+Ping+Pong+Orchestra/_/Kiss+the+Sky/+shoutbox - i.e. in reference to a musical orchestra. Therefore I assert the words 'family' and 'combo' are, in this case, referring to a group of musicians.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, Marv. The fact is though it's a common idiom; the OP should be aware of it, and we've described it at length!   And indeed he should also be aware of "combo" meaning musical band.  "Eg the Beatles were quite a combo, especially compared to the utterly vacuous unmusical marketing-created shit you hear on the internet these days"

Answer (score 0):

When using the word "combo" the writer *could* be referring to Shawn's band, the people who made the song the writer likes. It is impossible to tell without more context however [freedictionary.org](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=combo&button=Search) and others describe '*combo*' as meaning a small band of [jazz] musicians.

If Shawn is in musical band then this is more likely to be the intended meaning.

Comment: **However note**... for sure "combo" can mean "musical band".  But **"Quite a combo"** is an extremely well-established idiom.  So if you use "quite a combo", but you "cleverly" mean a "jazz combo" -- it's like a confusing "literal--pun" usage of the idiom.

Comment: I agree, but 'combo' does not not always refer to a jazz band despite what the dictionaries say- in the UK if you refer to a 'popular beat combo of the period' it will be understood that you are referring to a musical band, not specifically a jazz band. Secondly, it is hard to see what context this sentence above would make sense in, if referring to a 'family'. I'm not saying it's impossible, more that it is less likely- to refer to how much you like a song and also like someone else's family not connected with the song seems a stretch to me

Comment: I suspect the OP is referring to this usage: http://www.last.fm/music/Shawn+Lee's+Ping+Pong+Orchestra/_/Kiss+the+Sky/+shoutbox - In this case I believe this means that 'family' and 'combo' are referring to the musical orchestra.

Comment: (Hi Marv .. when I said jazz it was just a typo; I meant "any musical combo".  Sorry for the additional confusion!!)

Comment: It's quite disturbing we've all put so much time in to commenting on an irrelevant, sub literate, "SMS".  :O

Answer (score 0):

> **combo** (n.) 1929, U.S. slang, originally in entertainment (jazz groups,
> dance teams), short for combination, which was used by 1924 in the
> sense "small instrumental band." [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/combo)

The OED's earliest citation is from 1929.